# Как при каждом build'е проекта генерировать автоматически версию и записывать ее в глобальную переменную?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, version

Как сделать, что в проекте при build'е, генерировалась глобальная переменная с версией продукта (в данный момент вручную делается) и помещалась например в `window.version

Дополнительная информация:
Проект создан на основе "`react-boilerplate`"
Версия может быть в любом формате. Даже простой инкремент подойдет;

Comment: оно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310022/a-way-to-know-the-version-of-the-build-of-an-react-app ?

Comment: @KoVadim, похоже. Посмотрю, спасибо

Comment: там есть здравая идея использовать хеш текущего коммита как версию. Мне это очень нравится.